# can't keep a index using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a new JavaScript feature, in which i have a collection of media (img, video, txt...), the user can add a new media and once the media is added to the collection a new asynchronous request is send to the server for checking if the added media thumbnail already exist. if so the thumbnail is added to the media element in the collection.
 this the code that check if the thumbnail exist:

```
if (!img.width) {
  setTimeout(_.bind(function () {
    if (img.width) {
      this.$("mySelector").first().removeClass("nocover ").css('background-image', 'url('url of thumbnail');
    }
  }, this), 15000);
}
```

my problem is how to keep an index for a element whose check request was send to the server,because since this is asynchronous function sometimes while the request of the thumbnail check is being processed the user can add a new media element an then the thumbnail is added to wrong element. because my only way to refer to the new element is : 
this.$("mySelector").first()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the element to the function when setting the timeout.  This ensures that when the callback is called, it is provided with the same argument that was bound.

```
if (!img.width) {
  setTimeout((function ($elem) {
    if (img.width) {
      $elem.removeClass("nocover ").css('background-image', 'url(url of thumbnail)');
    }
  }).bind(this, this.$("mySelector").first()), 15000);
}
```